# TimeDistributed(Dense) vs Dense in seq2seq

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, seq2seq, encoder-decoder

Given the code below

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(16, 70))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(59, 93))
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs,_,_ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(93, activation='softmax'))
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

if I change

`decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(93, activation='softmax'))`

to

`decoder_dense = Dense(93, activation='softmax')`

it still work, but which method is more effective?

Answer (score 7):

If your Data is dependent on Time, like `Time Series` Data or the data comprising different frames of a `Video`, then Time `Distributed Dense` Layer is effective than simple `Dense` Layer.

`Time Distributed Dense` applies the same `dense` layer to every time step during `GRU/LSTM` Cell unrolling. That’s why the error function will be between the `predicted label sequence` and the `actual label sequence`.

Using `return_sequences=False`, the `Dense` layer will get applied only once in the last cell. This is normally the case when `RNNs` are used for classification problems.

If `return_sequences=True`, then the `Dense` layer is used to apply at every timestep just like `TimeDistributedDense`.

In your models both are the same, but if u change your second model to `return_sequences=False`, then the `Dense` will be applied only at the last cell.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!