# TimeDistributed(Dense) vs Dense And TimeDistributed(Conv2D)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to understand the how `TimeDitributed()` Layer works in keras!! I know that when we wrap `Conv2D` layer in `TimeDitributed()` it applies same Conv2D layer to all the time events of a video(or to different frames that are present in a video sequence). As mentioned here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed.

For the purpose of my project I am trying to build an LSTM model which is of the as follows:

```
class Lstm_model_1(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(Lstm_model_1, self).__init__()   
        self.Lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,return_sequences=True)
        self.Lstm2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,return_sequences=True) 
        self.classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
        self.TimeDistributed=tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(self.classifier)

    def call(self, inputs):
        input_A=inputs
        x = self.Lstm1(input_A)
        x = self.Lstm2(x)
        output = self.TimeDistributed(x)
        
        return  output
lstm_1 = Lstm_model_1(3)
lstm_1.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy())
lstm_1.fit(X_train,Y_train, epochs=3,validation_data=(X_test,Y_test))
lstm_1.summary()
Model: "lstm_model_1_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_9 (LSTM)                multiple                  55552     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_10 (LSTM)               multiple                  8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              multiple                  99        
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri multiple                  99        
=================================================================
Total params: 63,971
Trainable params: 63,971
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here I am getting 99 parameters in the `TimeDistributed()` layer.

Now when I am not using `TimeDistributed()` Layer I am getting same number of parameters i.e 99.

I have read in the following posts that :-

> If return_sequences=True, then the Dense layer is used to apply at every timestep just like TimeDistributedDense.

and

---

> As a side note: this makes TimeDistributed(Dense(...)) and Dense(...) equivalent to each other.

---

> Another side note: be aware that this has the effect of shared weights.""

---

1. [TimeDistributed(Dense) vs Dense in seq2seq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560304/timedistributeddense-vs-dense-in-seq2seq)
2. [Keras Dense layer's input is not flattened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089601/keras-dense-layers-input-is-not-flattened/52092176#52092176)

Now According to me it makes sense that the dense layer when applied on the LSTM `return_sequences=True` should have the same weights for the all the timestamps. But I have few questions that are mentioned below.

1. Is the `TimeDitributed()` wrapped with `Dense()` is redundant and can we use `Dense()` directly?
2. If let's say I don't want to use shared weights corresponding to the sequence outputs then what should I do? I want my network to learn different set of weights corresponding to each of the output in case of `return_sequences=True`
3. Why are we still wrapping our `Dense()` layer in the `TimeDitributed()` layer if both of them are sharing weights in the time squences? I have seen the usage of `TimeDitributed()` layer with `RepeatedVector()` layer here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46491/what-is-the-job-of-repeatvector-and-timedistributed
4. Is it only with the case of `Dense()` that `TimeDitribued()`  is redundant or is it also the same with `Conv2D` Layer?